# CSS being set as media and overridden

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure how to explain this. I'm using inspect element to configure css for elements. I find the element I want to make modifications to for instance:

```
  a.WTBText {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

I take what I found above in inspect element and add the following to my css.

```
  a.WTBText {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #105194;
}
```

When I refresh the page and inspect the element I see the following. The css I modified did not get applied. (same as before)

```
a.WTBText {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Just below this I see

```
 media screen
a.WTBText {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #105194;
}
```

Where is this media screen heading coming from? I am not placing the css under any media css queries.

Comment: In chrome, changes made in the `F12` /inspect element/console thingy are not persisted in page loads. You can edit, hit enter and see the results, but if you refresh, they are lost.

Answer (score 0):

The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices.

For instance, if you have @media (max-width: 300px) those values will only show on a device or screen that is under 300px wide. 
Check out this link. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: But the OP says: "I am not placing the css under any media css queries."

Comment: One more thing comes to mind, How many style sheets are you using, and is the value in any of those style sheets.

Comment: And changes in inspect element are not permanent, Once you change the value just hit enter for the new values to show. if you want to make them permanent, you must manually edit the css file itself.